# Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript working in IE and firefox but not in chrome

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, onload

I'm using

```
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onload", 
  "LoadGraphInitially(true)", true);
```

to attach a script on page load but it does'nt get fired in google chrome, though it works fine in IE and firefox.

Comment: Try ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Comment: tried dat too, but still not working

Comment: the way your question is written is saying your code behind isn't firing, is this what you mean? or do you mean the javascript isn't firing?

Comment: @peroija well i dont know wat u actually mean by dat.Usually when i try to register a client script from server side, i expect it to fire the javascript after page load, which is not happening in chrome

Comment: @jade `"LoadGraphInitially(true)"` ..add a `;` like this  ..`"LoadGraphInitially(true);"`

Comment: @user1042031 whoo...dat worked like a charm..thnks

Comment: @jade ..can I Post it as an anwser :D

Comment: ya ya sure.....though i already did :)

Comment: Ok never mind..Until it has solved ..cheers ;)

Comment: @user1042031 you should post an answer to get deserved upvotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @SJ GJ suggested

`"LoadGraphInitially(true)"` ..add a `;`   like this ..`"LoadGraphInitially(true);"` 
adding a `;` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add your javascript inside the HEAD tag. There is a trend where javascripts are written at the end of HTML block. It effects the loading of the page. But if in case you are registering your script from code behind on form load, then the script should be written inside the HEAD tag.